# Bummer, something went wrong - Is there an error log?

Tags: authentication

I am trying to set a LinkedIn button login via a Joomla Component.

I've provided credentials and added "Sign In with LinkedIn using OpenID Connect" to my app.

But when I try to login, I simply get a "Bummer, something went wrong" - that is not very helpful. How can I get additional info on what went wrong? Is there a log somewhere?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're using a browser there should be more information in the developer tools.  Often I'll get a redirect that has an error code in the URL for example.